# What is the bright red ingredient in Japanese chicken curry katsu?

Tags: food-identification, japanese-cuisine

I have had chicken curry katsu at different restaurants in different countries, and there is always a diced bright red ingredient, the color of a tomato, put on like a garnish. Some told me it was a red pepper, others a variety of carrot. I could not ascertain the flavor from eating a small bit of just that.

[image: bowl of curry rice from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Curry_rice_by_Hyougushi_in_Kyoto.jpg]

This picture seems to have it hiding in the back behind the rice, and I always have seen it served in a pile in the corner, although I often have seen it chopped into smaller bits.

Does anyone know what ingredient is used? Is that intended as a garnish not to be eaten?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This appears to be a Japanese pickle mixture, made with daikon radish amount other things, called Fukujinzuke (福神漬)

> Fukujinzuke is a mixture of Japanese radish (daikon), lotus root, cucumber and eggplant which are preserved in a soya sauce and sweet cooking wine (mirin) base. The sweet brown or red relish is served as a garnish to Japanese curry (kare raisu).

Source: https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2349.html

Answer (score -5):

The spice and color are in the title...

...curry.

Comment: "Curry" is not a spice. (There is a "curry tree", but it's not what you're thinking.) It's also not a bright red vegetable.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn more about how the site works. I sense the impulse to engage in a discussion in your posts, but this is a Q/A site with a rather strict format, unlike the standard web forums you may be familiar with z

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/84219)